# Using apache poi input Time

Tags: java, time, format, apache-poi

I have used Apahe POI to input the time into the excel file like following

```
Time time = Time.valueOf("19:30:00");
CellStyle cellStyle1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper1 = workbook.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle1.setDataFormat(
        createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:MM AM/PM"));
cell = row.getCell(1);
System.out.println(time.toString());
cell.setCellValue(time);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
```

which resulted into excel as expected however there was following mismatch found 
that actual value of excel and display value are different- How can i make them same , am i using incorrect way of updating the value in Excel Time format 
[image: Screenshot of output on Excel]

Comment: What do you want to see at the formula bar?

Comment: when i manually input the field with 07:30PM, it populates same in fomula bar

Comment: You could use Xcelite to write to Excel, it abstracts those things away - you just create a bean class and set date objects on it and it serializes to Excel: https://github.com/xcelite-io/xcelite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Excel* dates and times are stored as floating-point numbers, as amount of days since midnight *01/01/1900*.

If you will store some value less than `1.0` - it will be interpreted as a time, otherwise as a date, e.g.:

1. `0.5` will be equal to `12:00:00`
2. `5.5` will be equal to `05.01.1900  12:00:00`

To handle dates and times correctly please use `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil`, e.g. your example might look something like this:

```
    double time = DateUtil.convertTime("19:30:00");
    CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(
            workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:MM AM/PM"));
    cell.setCellValue(time);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

And the result *Excel* will look so:

[image: Excel time output]

---

Assume question was about the things described above, real date/time value in *Excel* should be a double and presentation value should be based on the style/pattern you've set; assume that goal was to achieve this kind of similarity, i.e. `19:30:00` in the formula and `07:30 PM` in the cell.

If no and the goal was to have `07:30 PM` in both cases - then you will just need to store a string value instead, not a date/time.

Comment: i tried Date date123 = calendar.getTime(); with styling and it worked fine , thanks for explaination ,I was using Open Office i guess there are different ways of handling the data in different Suits

Answer (score 0):

I use POI 3.17 and Excel from Office 365 ProPlus with Swedish locale. I added a few lines to your code (to create workbook and sheet, etc). The code below works fine. In the cell I get "07:30 PM" and in the formula bar "1970-01-01  19:30:00". If you don't get something similar when you run my code (using POI 3.17), my guess would be that something is a bit strange with your Excel.

```
public void createExcelFile() {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Time time = Time.valueOf("19:30:00");
    CellStyle cellStyle1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
    CreationHelper createHelper1 = workbook.getCreationHelper();
    cellStyle1.setDataFormat(createHelper1.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:MM AM/PM"));
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
    System.out.println(time.toString());
    cell.setCellValue(time);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/file.xlsx");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```